# Why does `cd` break redirects by `exec`?

Tags: bash, exec, io-redirection, cd

I'm trying to redirect parts of the output from a script to a file and have done it like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cleanup() {
  echo "Lines in $tmpfile:"
  cat $tmpfile
  rm $tmpfile
}

tmpfile=$(mktemp .tmp.`basename $0`.XXXXXX)
trap cleanup EXIT
for var in one two; do
  echo "$var: Before redirect"
  exec 6>&1           # Save stdout to descriptor #6
  exec >> "$tmpfile"  # Send output to file
  if [ 'a' == 'b' ]; then
    echo "this never happens"
  else
    echo "$var: line in file"
  fi
  exec 1>&6 # Restore stdout
  exec 6>&- # Close descriptor 6
  echo "$var: After redirect"
done
```

This produces the expected output:

```
$ ./test-working.sh
one: Before redirect
one: After redirect
two: Before redirect
two: After redirect
Lines in .tmp.test-working.sh.c3noO3:
one: line in file
two: line in file
```

If I do a small tweak like so however:

```
$ diff -u test-working.sh test-broken.sh
--- test-working.sh     2021-06-16 12:48:35.852500568 +0200
+++ test-broken.sh      2021-06-16 12:48:35.205483749 +0200
@@ -7,6 +7,7 @@

 tmpfile=$(mktemp .tmp.`basename $0`.XXXXXX)
 trap cleanup EXIT
+cd
 for var in one two; do
   echo "$var: Before redirect"
   exec 6>&1           # Save stdout to descriptor #6
@@ -20,3 +21,4 @@
   exec 6>&- # Close descriptor 6
   echo "$var: After redirect"
 done
+cd -
```

Then it breaks:

```
$ ./test-broken.sh
one: Before redirect
one: After redirect
two: Before redirect
two: After redirect
/script/run/path
Lines in .tmp.test-broken.sh.HSgMrS:
```

Using `set -x` you can clearly see that `echo` is writing something somewhere:

```
$ bash -x test-broken.sh
+++ basename test-broken.sh
++ mktemp .tmp.test-broken.sh.XXXXXX
+ tmpfile=.tmp.test-broken.sh.c6mf6c
+ trap cleanup EXIT
+ cd
+ for var in one two
+ echo 'one: Before redirect'
one: Before redirect
+ exec
+ exec
+ '[' a == b ']'
+ echo 'one: line in file'
+ exec
+ exec
+ echo 'one: After redirect'
one: After redirect
+ for var in one two
+ echo 'two: Before redirect'
two: Before redirect
+ exec
+ exec
+ '[' a == b ']'
+ echo 'two: line in file'
+ exec
+ exec
+ echo 'two: After redirect'
two: After redirect
+ cd -
/script/run/path
+ cleanup
+ echo 'Lines in .tmp.test-broken.sh.c6mf6c:'
Lines in .tmp.test-broken.sh.c6mf6c:
+ cat .tmp.test-broken.sh.c6mf6c
+ rm .tmp.test-broken.sh.c6mf6c
```

But it does not end up in the expected file. I'm struggling to see what I'm doing wrong. Why is `cd` breaking the redirect?

Comment: You're creating another file in the home directory with the same name and redirecting stdout to it. What else were you expecting to happen? Use `mktemp -p '' whatever` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, my code reads and writes to the same filename, but in different relative paths. Absolute paths fixes it:

```
$ diff -u test-broken.sh test-broken-fixed.sh
--- test-broken.sh      2021-06-16 13:21:30.301815257 +0200
+++ test-broken-fixed.sh        2021-06-16 13:22:03.222670969 +0200
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@
   rm $tmpfile
 }

-tmpfile="$(mktemp .tmp.`basename $0`.XXXXXX)"
+tmpfile="$PWD/$(mktemp .tmp.`basename $0`.XXXXXX)"
 trap cleanup EXIT
 cd
 for var in one two; do
```

Using `mktemp -p '' filename` would also work, then the file would land in `/tmp`.